# Sending automated Sharing Invitation for Task Folder results in Error

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, office-interop

I wrote an Outlook Addin that creates a Task folder. Then Tasks are created according to criteria.
Afterwards i want to send a sharing invitation. The Sharing Invitation Mail Window opens but automated sending results in an error "Error While Preparing to Send Sharing Message".
Funny thing is when i click "OK" on the error message and hit the send button manually it gets send how it should.
Googeling suggets to restore / repair certain folders or that is a permission problem.
I tested it on different machines with the same outcome. To make sure it is not a permission problem i seperated the logic into two buttons and it works, kinda.
When i hit the two buttons to quick i get the same error.
As far as i can see i relase all com objects from creating the tasks and the folder, but i seem to miss something important.

```
    private void CreateTask(string folderName, string taskName)
    {
        Outlook.NameSpace ns = null;
        Outlook.MAPIFolder taskFolder = null;
        Outlook.Items items = null;
        Outlook.TaskItem task = null;
        Outlook.Folder inBox = null;
        try
        {
            inBox = (Outlook.Folder)application.ActiveExplorer().Session.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderTasks);
            ns = application.GetNamespace("MAPI");
            taskFolder = inBox.Folders[folderName];
            items = taskFolder.Items;
            task = items.Add(Outlook.OlItemType.olTaskItem) as Outlook.TaskItem;
            task.Subject = taskName;
            task.Display(false);
            task.Close(Outlook.OlInspectorClose.olSave);             
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (task != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(task);
            if (items != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(items);
            if (taskFolder != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(taskFolder);
            if (ns != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(ns);
            if (inBox != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(inBox);
        }
    }

    public void CreateFolder(string Foldername)
    {
        Outlook.Folder inBox = (Outlook.Folder)application.ActiveExplorer().Session.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderTasks);
        Outlook.Folder customFolder = null;
        try
        {
            customFolder = (Outlook.Folder)inBox.Folders.Add(Foldername, Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderTasks);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("The following error occurred: " + ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (customFolder != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(customFolder);
            if (inBox != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(inBox);
        }
    }

    public void SendFolderShare(string taskFolderName, List<Task> tasks)
    {
        List<string> responsiblePersons = GetResponsiblePersons(tasks);

        Outlook.NameSpace nameSpace = null;
        Outlook.MAPIFolder taskFolder = null;
        Outlook.Folder folder = null;

        Outlook.Application oApp = new Outlook.Application();

        folder = (Outlook.Folder)application.ActiveExplorer().Session.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderTasks);

        nameSpace = application.GetNamespace("MAPI");
        taskFolder = folder.Folders[taskFolderName];
        Outlook.SharingItem sharingItem = nameSpace.CreateSharingItem(taskFolder);
        try
        {
            sharingItem.Subject = taskFolderName;
            sharingItem.To = String.Join(";", responsiblePersons);
            sharingItem.AllowWriteAccess = true;
            sharingItem.HTMLBody = GetHtmlBody(taskFolderName, tasks);
            sharingItem.Importance = Outlook.OlImportance.olImportanceHigh;
            sharingItem.Display(false);
            sharingItem.Send();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (taskFolder != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(taskFolder);
            if (nameSpace != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(nameSpace);
            if (folder != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(folder);
            if (sharingItem != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(sharingItem);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you get the same error if you try to do the same operations manually in Outlook?

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear in what sequence these methods are called in your solution.

However, I'd suggest starting from removing some line from the code, for example, to avoid permission issues I'd suggest commenting the following line of code:

```
sharingItem.AllowWriteAccess = true;
```

Also there is no need to display an item if you need to send it out immediately:

```
sharingItem.Display(false);
sharingItem.Send();
```

The same is for the other area in the code:

```
task.Display(false);
task.Close(Outlook.OlInspectorClose.olSave);
```

There is no need to call these methods, just call `Save()` and then release all underlying COM object references.